# AWS Cloudwatch Log - Is it possible to export existing log data from it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have managed to push my application logs to AWS Cloudwatch by using the AWS CloudWatch log agent. But the CloudWatch web console does not seem to provide a button to allow you to download/export the log data from it.

Any idea how I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The latest AWS CLI has a CloudWatch Logs cli, that allows you to download the logs as JSON, text file or any other output supported by AWS CLI.

For example to get the first 1MB up to 10,000 log entries from the stream `a` in group `A` to a text file, run:

```
aws logs get-log-events \
   --log-group-name A --log-stream-name a \
   --output text > a.log
```

The command is currently limited to a response size of maximum 1MB (up to 10,000 records per request), and if you have more you need to implement your own page stepping mechanism using the `--next-token` parameter. I expect that in the future the CLI will also allow full dump in a single command.

### Update

Here's a small Bash script to list events from all streams in a specific group, since a specified time:

```
#!/bin/bash
function dumpstreams() {
  aws $AWSARGS logs describe-log-streams \
    --order-by LastEventTime --log-group-name $LOGGROUP \
    --output text | while read -a st; do 
      [ "${st[4]}" -lt "$starttime" ] && continue
      stname="${st[1]}"
      echo ${stname##*:}
    done | while read stream; do
      aws $AWSARGS logs get-log-events \
        --start-from-head --start-time $starttime \
        --log-group-name $LOGGROUP --log-stream-name $stream --output text
    done
}

AWSARGS="--profile myprofile --region us-east-1"
LOGGROUP="some-log-group"
TAIL=
starttime=$(date --date "-1 week" +%s)000
nexttime=$(date +%s)000
dumpstreams
if [ -n "$TAIL" ]; then
  while true; do
    starttime=$nexttime
    nexttime=$(date +%s)000
    sleep 1
    dumpstreams
  done
fi
```

That last part, if you set `TAIL` will continue to fetch log events and will report newer events as they come in (with some expected delay).

Comment: In the first command of `aws cli` what is the backslash intended for? I think it brakes the command and that it is not needed. It should be `aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name A --log-stream-name a --output text > a.log`

Comment: You are obviously correct, but I'm using backslashes to break the command into multiple lines so it's easier to read in Stack Overflow's narrow display, and still be copy&pastable to your command line.

Comment: The `TAIL` logic doesn't really work when you have a large number of log files. For me, it takes several minutes to enumerate the log files in each iteration. (Also probably replace the fugly `while read -a` loop with an Awk one-liner; `awk -v after="$starttime" '$5 >= after { s = $2; gsub(/.*:/, "", s); print s }'` ... and [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee: (a) thank you for your comment, I'd appreciate seeing your full solution in an answer here :-) (b) Some people like AWK, I use it sparingly and Iike my `read -a` better - it is just a matter of style (c) some variables require quoting, others (like `$AWSARGS` here) require not-quoting - as per the link you provided, I don't quote my variables when they are numbers or otherwise safe. `$LOGGROUP` could probably use some quoting, though it is hardcoded and safe in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'm not critizising your code so much as adding a caveat for visitors whose scenario resembles mine. I don't think I can come up with a better solution; my workaround is to fetch the logs from the previous 24 hours in one go and then analyze them locally in batch.

Comment: @tripleee (a) that's cool. (b) I'm still pretty sure that if you post your code here, people will appreciate it 

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. When I do `dumpstreams.sh > streams.log` I get only two hours of events instead of 24 hours period that I've specified.

Comment: @SlavaFominII - Do you get the first 2 hours or the last 2 hours?

Comment: @Guss first two hours. BTW the `aws logs tail` command works great for me.

Comment: @SlavaFominII so it sounds like the "next" token is not handled correctly and you only get the first page. If `aws logs tail` works for you, then this is probably the correct solution - the above script was created in the begining times - when such advanced functionality in awscli was not even dreamed of 

Answer (score 50):

There is also a python project called `awslogs`, allowing to get the logs: https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs

There are things like:

list log groups:

```
$ awslogs groups
```

list streams for given log group:

```
$ awslogs streams /var/log/syslog
```

get the log records from all streams:

```
$ awslogs get /var/log/syslog
```

get the log records from specific stream :

```
$ awslogs get /var/log/syslog stream_A
```

and much more (filtering for time period, watching log streams...

I think, this tool might help you to do what you want.

Comment: I don't see the timestamp for each record. Any reason why this is suppressed? It's visible via CloudWatch Logs in the AWS console.

Comment: @sharmil try the `--timestamp` option

Comment: How foolish of me. I see it in the documents. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky sir I want to ask one thing, How we can log our form data over cloudwatch using php ?

Comment: @ChitrangSharma I am not expert on PHP, but I have found, there is an PHP AWS SDK and there is client to interact with AwsCloudWatchLogs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CloudWatchLogs.CloudWatchLogsClient.html

Answer (score 27):

It seems AWS has added the ability to export an entire log group to S3.

[image: Export to S3 menu]

[image: Export to S3 Form]

You'll need to setup permissions on the S3 bucket to allow cloudwatch to write to the bucket by adding the following to your bucket policy, replacing the region with your region and the bucket name with your bucket name.

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tsf-log-data"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tsf-log-data/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    }
```

Details can be found in [Step 2 of this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html)

Answer (score 18):

The other answers were not useful with AWS Lambda logs since they create many log streams and I just wanted to dump everything in the last week. I finally found the following command to be what I needed:

```
aws logs tail --since 1w  LOG_GROUP_NAME > output.log
```

Note that LOG_GROUP_NAME is the lambda function path (e.g. /aws/lambda/FUNCTION_NAME) and you can replace the since argument with a variety of times (1w = 1 week, 5m = 5 minutes, etc)

Comment: We can also use `... --log-stream-names STREAM_NAME ...` to retrieve specific instances logs. Final: `aws logs tail --since 1w  LOG_GROUP_NAME --log-stream-names STREAM_NAME > output.log`

Comment: Very helpful for ECS logs as well, where each task in the cluster has its own log stream!

Comment: This works well, the accepted answer didn't work for sagemaker training jobs logs where there was multiple streams due to training stopping/resuming. I only got the tail of the last log stream using `get-log-events`

Comment: This works like a charm. It should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would add that one liner to get all logs for a stream :

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name my-log-group --log-stream-name my-log-stream | grep '"message":' | awk -F '"' '{ print $(NF-1) }' > my-log-group_my-log-stream.txt
```

Or in a slightly more readable format :

```
aws logs get-log-events \
    --log-group-name my-log-group\
    --log-stream-name my-log-stream \
    | grep '"message":' \
    | awk -F '"' '{ print $(NF-1) }' \
    > my-log-group_my-log-stream.txt
```

And you can make a handy script out of it that is admittedly less powerful than @Guss's but simple enough. I saved it as `getLogs.sh` and invoke it with `./getLogs.sh log-group log-stream`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "${#}" != 2 ]]
then
    echo "This script requires two arguments!"
    echo
    echo "Usage :"
    echo "${0} <log-group-name> <log-stream-name>"
    echo
    echo "Example :"
    echo "${0} my-log-group my-log-stream"

    exit 1
fi

OUTPUT_FILE="${1}_${2}.log"
aws logs get-log-events \
    --log-group-name "${1}"\
    --log-stream-name "${2}" \
    | grep '"message":' \
    | awk -F '"' '{ print $(NF-1) }' \
    > "${OUTPUT_FILE}"

echo "Logs stored in ${OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

Comment: any idea why im getting an Unknown output type: None

Comment: Remember, anything which looks like `grep 'x' | awk '{ y }'` can and probably should be refactored to `awk '/x/ { y }'`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there isn't an out-of-box way from AWS Console where you can download the CloudWatchLogs. Perhaps you can write a script to perform the CloudWatchLogs fetch using the SDK / API.

The good thing about CloudWatchLogs is that you can retain the logs for infinite time(Never Expire); unlike the CloudWatch which just keeps the logs for just 14 days. Which means you can run the script in monthly / quarterly frequency rather than on-demand.

More information about the CloudWatchLogs API,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html 
http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudwatchlogs/latest/cwl-api.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can now perform exports via the Cloudwatch Management Console with the new Cloudwatch Logs Insights page. Full documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ExportQueryResults.html. I had already started ingesting my Apache logs into Cloudwatch with JSON, so YMMV if you haven't set it up in advance.

> Add Query to Dashboard or Export Query Results
>
> After you run a query, you can add the query to a CloudWatch
>   dashboard, or copy the results to the clipboard.
>
> Queries added to dashboards automatically re-run every time you load
>   the dashboard and every time that the dashboard refreshes. These
>   queries count toward your limit of four concurrent CloudWatch Logs
>   Insights queries.
>
> To add query results to a dashboard
>
> Open the CloudWatch console at
>   https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Insights.
>
> Choose one or more log groups and run a query.
>
> Choose Add to dashboard.
>
> Select the dashboard, or choose Create new to create a new dashboard
>   for the query results.
>
> Choose Add to dashboard.
>
> To copy query results to the clipboard
>
> Open the CloudWatch console at
>   https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Insights.
>
> Choose one or more log groups and run a query.
>
> Choose Actions, Copy query results.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by saputkin I have created a pyton script that downloads all the logs for a log group in given time period.

The script itself: https://github.com/slavogri/aws-logs-downloader.git

In case there are multiple log streams for that period multiple files will be created. Downloaded files will be stored in current directory, and will be named by the log streams that has a log events in given time period. (If the group name contains forward slashes, they will be replaced by underscores. Each file will be overwritten if it already exists.)

Prerequisite: You need to be logged in to your aws profile. The Script itself is going to use on behalf of you the AWS command line APIs: "aws logs describe-log-streams" and "aws logs get-log-events"

```
Usage example: python aws-logs-downloader -g /ecs/my-cluster-test-my-app -t "2021-09-04 05:59:50 +00:00" -i 60

optional arguments:
   -h, --help         show this help message and exit
   -v, --version      show program's version number and exit
   -g , --log-group   (required) Log group name for which the log stream events needs to be downloaded
   -t , --end-time    (default: now) End date and time of the downloaded logs in format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z (example: 2021-09-04 05:59:50 +00:00)
   -i , --interval    (default: 30) Time period in minutes before the end-time. This will be used to calculate the time since which the logs will be downloaded.
   -p , --profile     (default: dev) The aws profile that is logged in, and on behalf of which the logs will be downloaded.
   -r , --region      (default: eu-central-1) The aws region from which the logs will be downloaded.
```

Please let me now if it was useful to you. :)

After I did it I learned that there is another option using Boto3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events

Still the command line API seems to me like a good option.

Answer (score 1):

`` export LOGGROUPNAME=[SOME_LOG_GROUP_NAME]; for LOGSTREAM in `aws --output text logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name ${LOGGROUPNAME} |awk '{print $7}'`; do aws  --output text logs get-log-events --log-group-name ${LOGGROUPNAME} --log-stream-name ${LOGSTREAM} >> ${LOGGROUPNAME}_output.txt; done ``

Answer (score 0):

Adapted @Guyss answer to macOS. As I am not really a bash guy, had to use python, to convert dates to a human-readable form.

`runaswslog -1w` gets last week and so on

```
runawslog() { sh awslogs.sh $1 | grep "EVENTS" | python parselogline.py; }
```

awslogs.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
function dumpstreams() {
  aws $AWSARGS logs describe-log-streams \
    --order-by LastEventTime --log-group-name $LOGGROUP \
    --output text | while read -a st; do 
      [ "${st[4]}" -lt "$starttime" ] && continue
      stname="${st[1]}"
      echo ${stname##*:}
    done | while read stream; do
      aws $AWSARGS logs get-log-events \
        --start-from-head --start-time $starttime \
        --log-group-name $LOGGROUP --log-stream-name $stream --output text
    done
}
AWSARGS=""
#AWSARGS="--profile myprofile --region us-east-1"
LOGGROUP="/aws/lambda/StockTrackFunc"
TAIL=
FROMDAT=$1
starttime=$(date -v ${FROMDAT} +%s)000
nexttime=$(date +%s)000
dumpstreams
if [ -n "$TAIL" ]; then
  while true; do
    starttime=$nexttime
    nexttime=$(date +%s)000
    sleep 1
    dumpstreams
  done
fi
```

parselogline.py:

```
import sys
import datetime
dat=sys.stdin.read()
for k in dat.split('\n'):
    d=k.split('\t')
    if len(d)<3:
        continue
    d[2]='\t'.join(d[2:])
    print( str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d[1])/1000)) + '\t' + d[2] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case where i had to download all the streams for a given log group. See if this script helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "${#}" != 1 ]]
then
    echo "This script requires two arguments!"
    echo
    echo "Usage :"
    echo "${0} <log-group-name>"

    exit 1
fi

streams=`aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name "${1}"`


for stream in $(jq '.logStreams | keys | .[]' <<< "$streams"); do 
    record=$(jq -r ".logStreams[$stream]" <<< "$streams")
    streamName=$(jq -r ".logStreamName" <<< "$record")
    echo "Downloading ${streamName}";
    echo `aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "${1}" --log-stream-name "$streamName" --output json > "${stream}.log" `
    echo "Completed dowload:: ${streamName}";
done;
```

You have have pass log group name as an argument.

> Eg: bash <name_of_the_bash_file>.sh <group_name>

Answer (score 0):

For stream with more than 10000 events, it is more resilient to use the `forward token` and `start-from-head` for the log stream. It avoids issues with empty/duplicate events if time not exactly right or events are too dense.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Required parameters
REGION="PLACEHOLDER"
LOG_GROUP_NAME="PLACEHOLDER"
LOG_STREAM_NAME="PLACEHOLDER"

# Temporary files
TEMP_FILE="temp_output.txt"
FINAL_OUTPUT_FILE="final_output.txt"

# Initial command
aws logs get-log-events --region $REGION --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --log-stream-name $LOG_STREAM_NAME --start-from-head --output text > $TEMP_FILE

# Check number of lines in the file
while [ $(wc -l <"$TEMP_FILE") -gt 1 ]
do
  # Get the next token
  NEXT_TOKEN=$(grep -o -E "^b/[0-9]+/s\s+f/[0-9]+/s$" $TEMP_FILE |awk '{print $2}')

  # If we didn't find a next token, exit the loop
  if [ -z "$NEXT_TOKEN" ]; then
    break
  fi

  # Remove token line from temp file and append to final output file
  grep -v -o -E "^b/[0-9]+/s\s+f/[0-9]+/s$" temp_output.txt  $TEMP_FILE >> $FINAL_OUTPUT_FILE
  
  # Fetch more logs with the next token
  aws logs get-log-events --region $REGION --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --log-stream-name $LOG_STREAM_NAME --next-token $NEXT_TOKEN --output text > $TEMP_FILE
done

# Append remaining content in temp file to final output file
grep -v -o -E "^b/[0-9]+/s\s+f/[0-9]+/s$" temp_output.txt  $TEMP_FILE >> $FINAL_OUTPUT_FILE

# Cleanup
rm $TEMP_FILE
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the line that $TEMP_FILE to $FINAL_OUTPUT_FILE

Answer (score 0):

I use windows and was inspired by Slavomir, i written a goLang program and built the awsLogExport.exe to call the aws log command to retrieve the from a time range.

Source Code is in following link:
https://github.com/onionhead0708/awsExportLog/blob/main/awsExportLog.go

You can build the awsLogExport.exe with following command:

```
go build
```

Following is an example to export the log messages to myLogfile.log for the log that started from 2024-01-13T14:25:00Z for 1 hour log:

```
awsExportLog.exe -r=us-west-2 -g=/aws/containerinsights/my-log-group -s=mytest.restapi -f=2024-01-13T14:25:00Z -d=1h > myLogfile.log
```

Arguments:

```
  -d string
        Duration of the log to be taken from the From time. e.g. 1m1s = 1 minute 1 second (default "1h")
  -f string
        From time in RFC3339 format. e.g.: 2024-02-13T14:25:60Z
  -g string
        AWS log group name
  -r string
        AWS region
  -s string
        AWS log stream name
```

Prerequisite:

1. You need to install the AWS CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html
2. You need to logged in to your aws profile.

Note: awsExportLog.exe just call the AWS command line APIs: "aws logs get-log-events"

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here, just wanted to add what I found , kind of tricky too.I just wanted to download the entire log stream logs for one of the support case I was working on.

Below command works only on the latest log stream.

```bash
$ aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name  'my_log_group' \
--log-stream-name  'my_stream_name' --output text
```

If the log stream is not latest, we need to specify the [--start-from-head](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html#CWL-GetLogEvents-request-startFromHead) flag otherwise it will not give you the logs

without `--start-from-head` flag

```bash
$ aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name  'my_log_group' \
--log-stream-name  'my_stream_name' --output text

b/3812585230811583357791156477815594204/s    f/38126173438735188692892143032919214/s
```

with `--start-from-head` flag

```bash
$ aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name  'my_log_group' \
--log-stream-name  'my_stream_name' --output text

b/3812585230811583357791156477815594204/s    f/3812617343873518869289214303291960224/s
EVENTS  1709568940700   INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.12.v29    
Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:2fb93380dac14772d30092f171a3f757
```

Below is the snippet from the [aws cli docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html)

```
--start-from-head | --no-start-from-head (boolean)
If the value is true, the earliest log events are returned first. If
the value is false,
the latest log events are returned first. The default value is false.

If you are using a previous nextForwardToken value as the nextToken in this operation,
you must specify true for startFromHead .
```

Answer (score -1):

I found AWS Documentation to be complete and accurate. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html
This laid down steps for exporting logs from Cloudwatch to S3