# send old aws lambda logs to aws kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I just created a new AWS kinesis stream and have it set up to receive data I am pulling in a lambda function. Theres is some data in my cloud watch logs that came in before I had my stream set up. Is there a way to get manually send this to kinesis?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677049/7207514) to export CloudWatch logs as JSON/txt/etc. afterwhich you could design some sort of script to iterate through those logs and put them into your Kinesis stream