# Extract historical data from Aws cloudwatch for monthly report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I extract the historical metrics data from aws cloudwatch and generate monthly report on the instance health check? I'm looking for free tools that can be used.

If I subscripe to detail AWS cloudwatch, will I be able to export the matrices historical data to eg excel?

Appreciate your help! 
Su

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer [AWS Cloudwatch Log - Is that possible to export existing log data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060845/aws-cloudwatch-log-is-that-possible-to-export-existing-log-data-from-it)

Excel is not one of the supported format but full cloudwatch information is available as text and you should be able to export it for further processing

Otherwise, you can see Cloudwatch to ElasticSearch option

Comment: Does cloudwatch logs capture the Ram, cpu utilisation and bandwidth of the instances?

Comment: Ram usage is not captures by default

Comment: How can I configure to capture the Ram usage?

Comment: You will need to install a software - the Cloudwatch Agent on your machine https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html

By default AWS manage the CPU Util and Network In / Out but not RAM usage

Answer (score 0):

because the monthly report is a routine work, you can try [categraf cloudwatch plugin](https://github.com/flashcatcloud/categraf/tree/main/inputs/cloudwatch) . It can easily export cloud-watch metrics to your Prometheus then you can visualize data using grafana and export to csv.

And further more, you can also try [nightingale project](https://github.com/ccfos/nightingale) which can be an alternative of prometheus&grafana.